# Angular, how to reload data with given Id from another component on click event

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular2 application, I have component which loading some responses with button click event. This component has it own data loads responses via Web API call. At the end of this template, I am loading questions . Now my question is how to reload this  with each loadNextResponse() and loadPreviousResponse() click event???

questions list are bind by response Id, which I am getting on loadNextResponse() and loadPreviousResponse() click event.

### Response template

```
<div *ngIf='responseData'>
    <div *ngFor="let response of responses" class="form-row">
       {{response.responseId}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1><span>response  </span>{{currentResponse.responseId}}</h1> 

        <button class="btn btn-default width-50 mb-xs" id = "{{currentResponseIndex}}" (click)="loadNextResponse(currentResponseIndex)">Load Next Response</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default width-50 mb-xs" id = "{{currentResponseIndex}}" (click)="loadPreviousResponse(currentResponseIndex)">Load Previous Response</button>
    </div>  

</div>

  <div>       
      <questionsDetailList></questionsDetailList>       
      <!-- <questionsDetailList [responseId]="currentResponse.responseId" ></questionsDetailList>-->
  </div>
```

### Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'new-response-questions',
  templateUrl: './new-response-question.template.html',
})

export class NewResponseComponent implements OnInit {

 public loadData():void
 {
      //load data from Web Api
 }

  public loadNextResponse(responseIndex: string):void
 {
        //load next response
 }

  public loadPreviousResponse(responseIndex: string):void
 {
        // load previous response
 }

}
```

### Question component

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'questionsDetailList',
  templateUrl: './question.template.html',
 })

@Input() responseId:string;  ??????????

export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.view = new BehaviorSubject<QuestionsDataModel>(null);
     this.loadData();
 }

 public loadData():void
 {
   //load questions from web api //
 }
}
```

Comment: Simply use ngOnChange in the **questionsDetailList** component

Comment: can you help me out how to use ngOnChange, I am new to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **ngOnChange()** to **questionsDetailList** component like below :

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'questionsDetailList',
  templateUrl: './question.template.html',
 })

@Input() responseId:string;  ??????????

export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges  {

//This function will fire when this.responseId get change
ngOnChanges() {
     this.loadData();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.view = new BehaviorSubject<QuestionsDataModel>(null);
     this.loadData();
 }

 public loadData():void
 {
   //load questions from web api //
 }
}
```

Then use you'r component like below

```
<questionsDetailList [responseId]="requestId"></questionsDetailList>
```

After that you just need to change the value of **requestId** and as soon as it's value get changes , the **ngOnChanges()** function inside **questionsDetailList**  component will load.